# Como apagar a última div adicionada pelo DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo um webapp de notas, usei DOM para adicionar notas e remover, porém quando removo, ele remove a primeira nota e não a última.

```
<script async>
        function novaNota() {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id = "div";
            div.style = "background-color: coral; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px silver; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px;";
            document.body.appendChild(div);

            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.id = "input";
            input.type = "checkbox";
            input.style = "width: 25px; height: 25px; margin-left: 25%;";
            div.appendChild(input);

            var nome = prompt("Adicionar:");
            var p = document.createElement(p);
            p.textContent = nome;
            p.style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left: 5%";
            div.appendChild(p);
        }
        function removerNota() {
            var div = document.getElementById("div");
            document.body.removeChild(div);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro que acontence no seu código é dévido a você está usando o identificador (Atributo ID) dos elementos criados com o mesmo nome, sendo que o ID de um elemento deve ser únido, não podendo ser usado em outros elementos, que é o que ocorre no seu código, contudo, quando isso acontece o elemento que será retornando pela função `getElementById` será o primeiro elemento da página com o nome do ID passado da chamada da função.

Você pode resolver seu problema usando classe (Atributo class) ao ínves de id para pegar o último elemento inserido na página, como no exemplo que se segue abaixo baseado no seu código:

```js
function novaNota() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "div";
  div.className = "div";
  div.style = "background-color: coral; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px silver; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px;";
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input";
  input.type = "checkbox";
  input.style = "width: 25px; height: 25px; margin-left: 25%;";
  div.appendChild(input);

  var nome = prompt("Adicionar:");
  var p = document.createElement(p);
  p.textContent = nome;
  p.style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left: 5%";
  div.appendChild(p);
}
function removerNota() {
  var allDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("div"),
    div = allDiv[allDiv.length - 1];
  document.body.removeChild(div);
}

novaNota()
novaNota()
removerNota();
```